# Housenumber(point) angle from line (street)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, point, line, proximity

using arcgis 10 with Point data (Housenumber without angle attribute) and line data (street without angle attribute)

I want to create housenumber labels from point with correct angle from nearest streetline.

Is there any toolbox for this?.

my thinking of this is calculate AVERAGE streetline angle and then somehow put this values to nearest point?

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a tool for that in ET GEoWizards (Point Angle and Position), you can download it here: http://www.ian-ko.com/. It doesn't work in the free version, but the paid version is worth every penny!

Comment: you saved me hours in research :)

Answer (score 2):

Run the Near toolbox - Analysis Tools, Proximity, Near. This requires an ArcInfo license. Be sure to check or enable the Angle option. When enabled a field named Near_Angle will be added to your Point data. This is the angle from each Point to the nearest feature. You can use the Label Toolbar to place your housenumbers at this angle.

Comment: This works aswell, interseting thing is the angle attribute is arithmetic on one and geographic on the other, do you know some explanation on the difference between these angle options?

Comment: geographic - zero degree is north, increasing clockwise<br/>
graphic - zero degree is north, increasing counter clockwise<br/>
arithmetic - zero degree is horizontal or east, increasing counter clockwise